# Kernel Panic causing crash OSX10.10.5

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

So I've been having a lot of kernel panics over the past few months, and the apple store says it's not hardware. I've taken it in several times under apple care (Still covered for one more year) and they have replaced the logic board.

Every time it crashes I look at the offending program and remove it. This one however I don't know.

Here is the log:

```
Tue Sep  8 09:54:18 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800b616df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800b5cf4a5, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000007, CR3: 0x00000003141760e3, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff800bce0cb0, RBX: 0x000000000000003d, RCX: 0xffffff800bce08e0, RDX: 0xffffffffffffffff
RSP: 0xffffff81fa7e3400, RBP: 0xffffff81fa7e3410, RSI: 0xffffff8028d5b240, RDI: 0x000000000000003d
R8:  0x000000000000008d, R9:  0xffffff801ef7fb80, R10: 0x0000000000000100, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff8034b90c30, R13: 0xffffff802d1cc400, R14: 0xffffff801efc8f40, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010297, RIP: 0xffffff800b5cf4a5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000007, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81fa7e30b0 : 0xffffff800b52ad21 
0xffffff81fa7e3130 : 0xffffff800b616df2 
0xffffff81fa7e32f0 : 0xffffff800b633ca3 
0xffffff81fa7e3310 : 0xffffff800b5cf4a5 
0xffffff81fa7e3410 : 0xffffff800b5c134b 
0xffffff81fa7e3740 : 0xffffff800b9fcbed 
0xffffff81fa7e3770 : 0xffffff800b732750 
0xffffff81fa7e3830 : 0xffffff800b7375ed 
0xffffff81fa7e38a0 : 0xffffff800b735d41 
0xffffff81fa7e3a60 : 0xffffff800b732342 
0xffffff81fa7e3d20 : 0xffffff800b93e8b8 
0xffffff81fa7e3db0 : 0xffffff800b764141 
0xffffff81fa7e3e50 : 0xffffff800b9eba4a 
0xffffff81fa7e3ef0 : 0xffffff800b9eb7b3 
0xffffff81fa7e3f50 : 0xffffff800ba4b376 
0xffffff81fa7e3fb0 : 0xffffff800b6344a6 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: java

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x000000000b200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800b400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800b300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 7930510307163
last loaded kext at 4203882668416: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch    85.3 (addr 0xffffff7f8de01000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 4296192694120: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f8ddba000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  264.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0B, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331312D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331312D38475351000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: sorry, what I'm trying to find is the cause of this one

Comment: -1 for details. Removing an app due to kernel panics needs finer explanation and specifics. Are you removing system components? Why haven't you uninstalled Java entirely? What is the frequency of panics since the last system update / modification you have performed. Can you cause a panic or is is a rare occurrence?

Comment: I've had several over the last few months, mostly related to software I had installed such as Duet, and a few other programs. I have since uninstalled and removed any remanences of them. Saying it's java isn't really specific, considering how many things are running java. It doesn't even say what version of java it was using for me to uninstall.
I get them about once a week, but all different causes. It's usually when I'm compiling code, but not always. I've had my computer sitting idle and have had a crash

Comment: What hardware are you using? Press `D` during startup to test your RAM.

Comment: I'll be doing that when I get home from work. I have a mid 2013 MBP. I recently installed more ram, although this problem is older than that. I did do memetest but again I'll do it again tonight and update.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stank dump you posted, you have no 3rd-party kexts loaded.  USB devices cannot cause a kernel panic, and Java is sandboxed.  Therefore, the only option left is the RAM you chose.

Macs are MUCH more sensitive to RAM than PCs are.  The RAM you choose must be DDR3 1600MHz and support a CAS latency of 11 at 1.35v.

If you purchased RAM that has different specs (even if they're better), then it's not compatible.  Often times, faster memory requires higher voltages or have more relaxed timings to achieve those speeds.  PCs have no problems with this because the SPD chip tells the memory controller what timings the RAM supports.  But because Apple cherry-picks their hardware for their own platform, Macs ignore those settings in favor of the RAM that Apple specifically chose for that model.  The RAM timings and voltage are fixed by the firmware.

You don't mention what RAM you bought, but CAS latency and voltage are not the usual marketing specs you'd find when shopping for memory.  You have to specifically look for those specs.  Assuming you bought off-the-shelf RAM, it's likely being undervolted by the power management capabilities of your Mac.  A memtest wouldn't pick up on that because the RAM is good (when it has full power), so all the cells would check out OK.

If you did shop around and bought memory specifically certified for your Mac, I'd still blame the RAM and try to have it exchanged.  There's nothing in that panic report that would indicate you have a software problem.

Comment: Yeah, tonight I'll run memtest86. When I was shopping I asked for MacRam at a reputable place, he did sell me a set. He told me they didn't have the certified apple sticker on them, but was compatible. It is 1600MHz, don't remember the latency off my head.

Comment: I've checked the RAM and all seems good. It passed the built in diagnostic, and I ran MemTest86 overnight with no errors with 4 passes.

Answer (score 0):

For random panics like this, the first thing I'd suspect is faulty RAM or bad third party kernel extensions, badly written applications shouldn't be able to cause kernel panics. From the panic report there don't seem to be any third-party extensions, so I'd check the RAM in your Mac.

There are diagnostic tools built into Macs to test, amongst other things, your RAM. Power down your Macbook, then power it on and hold down the D key. This should launch Apple Hardware Test. Within you should find Basic and Extended tests. Try them and see if it finds any problems with your Macbook's RAM.

You can read more here.
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201257

If you want to be really thorough there are other memtest utilities available online, that might find faults that Apple's tests don't.

http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/

http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/

Comment: I will check the RAM. I did install new ram recently, however I thought I did a full pass with memtest86

Comment: I've checked the RAM and all seems good. It passed the built in diagnostic, and I ran MemTest86 overnight with no errors with 4 passes.

Comment: Sometimes there can be problems the tests don't catch. Do you still have the original RAM? Can you try running the machine for a while with just the original RAM in the laptop? See if the panics still happen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still have the original 8GB RAM, and the crashes actually started on that. I only recently upgraded to 16GB, because my work needs it. While working I usually average around 10GB used, so going back isn't an option for me. Not to mention that these crashes are about 6 months old, while the RAM is about 3 weeks old.

Comment: Well if it was happening with old RAM and now with completely different RAM then it's unlikely to be the RAM. :) When the MacBook panics do you have any other devices plugged in? If so can you try running for a while with nothing plugged in?

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to think about that. I think the only thing I've had plugged in every time it's occurred has been my external monitor (thunderbolt to VGA or DVI) and my bluetooth magic mouse. The other curious thing is before the crash there is always screen glitches, but not all screen glitches are followed by a crash.